# Android Studio says JDK 7 isn't Installed, while JDK 8 is even installed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to compile in Android Studio, the program says that sdkVersion 21 requires compiling with JDK is required. Although I installed JDK 7 (and later 8) and my terminal says that they were installed, only the 1.6.0.blabla version is visible as an installed Java Virtual Machine in my folders... How can I fix this?

Comment: You are on Windows, Linux, MacOS ? What does: "javac -version" say ?

Comment: I'm on a mac OSX 10.10, java-version says "javac 1.8.0_25"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I am on Windows, so pathname format would be different, but rest of the steps should work fine.

In Android Studio, go to:  **File > Project Structure > SDK Location** and make sure that the **JDK  Location** property has valid path pointing to JDK installed on your system.

On Windows, that property value is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55", so you can make a good guess as to what it should be on MacOS.